# Plupload - Event not firing

Tags: javascript, file-upload, plupload

I am using the below code to fire an event when the upload queue has completed, however i can not seem to get it working..

Any ideas?

```
var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue(
{
    runtimes       : 'html5,html4',
    url            : '/admin/media/image_upload',
    max_file_size  : '1mb',
    unique_names   : true,
    filters        : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}]
});

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, res)
{
    alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is relevant, but I use it slightly differently :

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue(
{
    runtimes       : 'html5,html4',
    url            : '/admin/media/image_upload',
    max_file_size  : '1mb',
    unique_names   : true,
    filters        : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}]
});

var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue();

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, res)
{
alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that overwrite the first plupload instance?

Comment: I guess not. That's how they get to the queue in the following example : http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

Answer (score 1):

You may like another way:

Additional property added to your **$("#uploader").pluploadQueue()** :

```
init: {
    FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
    // Called when file has finished uploading
    console.log('[FileUploaded] File:', file, "Info:", info);
    }
}
```

So the uploader code will be:

```
var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue(
{
    runtimes       : 'html5,html4',
    url            : '/admin/media/image_upload',
    max_file_size  : '1mb',
    unique_names   : true,
    filters        : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}],
    init: {
        FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
        // Called when file has finished uploading
        console.log('[FileUploaded] File:', file, "Info:", info);
        }
    }
});
```

I've found this in source examples - http://www.plupload.com/examples/events